# Different Screen Sizes?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I been working on a winodws 7 phone. I am wondering if there are different sizes that I have to account for? Or is it the case that if my app looks fine in the windows emulator then it will look fine on the actual phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WP7 devices in the world has only one screen size, 480x800.

Now that WP8 has released, there're also WP8 devices, with 1280x768 and 1280x720 screens.

Comment: You don't have to concern yourself with the WP8 resolutions (WXGA and 720p) until you release a WP8 app.  What you see in the emulator is fine for WP7

Comment: @kindasimple, the backward compatibility is not ideal. I've got several "1" marks from unhappy WP8 users complaining my WP7-only app doesn't work as expected on their devices.

Comment: I believe it. Personally, I would release a separate WP8 app and deal with resolution issues there.
http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Multi_resolution